# calling a visual studio dll from delphi or lazarus

Tags: delphi, dll, lazarus

I need to call a dll from delphi 7 or lazarus. The information on the dll is minimal but I have an example of its use in visual studio:
Declarations:

```
    [DllImport("landwell.dll", EntryPoint = "PTcomm", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int PTcomm(int com, int boud, ref int Rcount);
    [DllImport("landwell.dll", EntryPoint = "PTcomm_YPWJ", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int PTcomm_YPWJ(int com, int boud, ref int Rcount);

    [DllImport("landwell.dll", EntryPoint = "PTrecord", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int PTrecord(int num,byte[] record);
```

How do I declare and call these functions in Delphi 7 or Lazarus?

The only documentation I have is:
1、Common Transmit:
   PTcomm(int com,int boud,int *Rcount)
   Com is for serial port number,boud rate is 9600, *Rcount is for recording the total    number
   "1" means returning successfully, "0 "means no record,"-1”means opening the port    unsuccessfully,“-2 ”means transmiting unsuccessfully

2、Common collecting data
   PTrecord(int num，byte record[8])
   record{8} means 8byte(including the reader number), num means the serial number
   "1" means return successfully,"0" means return unsuccessfully
I only have an example in Visual Studio which I cannot even try as it was written in an older version of VS and the automatic conversion did not work. At this time I have no intention of learning VS. The declarations mentionned earlier in the post come from that example.
I have been accused of not even trying by someone who does not know me and has no idea of what I did. I tried and failed which is the reason I am asking.

Thanks, Jean-Claude

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Rudy The code in the Q is how to call the unmanaged dll from C# using PInvoke.

Comment: @David: yes, I just realized that and removed my comment. <g>

Comment: @Jean You have not made any effort to solve the problem. Please try. There are plenty of tutorials on the subject.

Comment: @Jean-Claude: does the DLL come with a C header? That would be much more useful than a "translation" of (parts of) such a header for PInvoke.

Comment: It's not cool that you tell us that you don't want to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these declarations in Delphi and Lazarus:

```pascal
function PTcomm(com, boud: Integer; var Rcount: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external 'landwell.dll';

function PTcomm_YPWJ(com, boud: Integer; var Rcount: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external 'landwell.dll';

function PTrecord(num: Integer; rec: PByte): Integer; stdcall; external 'landwell.dll';
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, I will try and let you know

Comment: Thanks Remy, that did it. My main mistake was passing pointers instead of var And contrary to what David says I learned a lot.